# Windows 7 Sleep issues - GPU dying?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, sleep, gpu

My PC has been having issues coming out of sleep lately. I've searched most related topics around here but couldn't find an answer to completely relate to - although I tried some of the solutions mentioned on various answers, with no luck.

I think I've identified the issue to be the GPU ( ATI HD5770 ), but I would like to confirm it as it seems to be causing troubles only coming out of sleep, otherwise it works perfectly, even with games I play at FullHD.

The first hint was one day that I moved my mouse and I got it awake but the screen was distorted. I could move the mouse but **the resolution was something like 1920x600 cramped at the middle of the screen**. Everything was working properly but I couldn't "fix" that without a reboot.

I updated my GPU drivers ( full uninstall/install ) to the latest, opened the tower to clean it + some blowing in the GPU and waited to see how it'll react.

Today, I tried bringing it out of sleep and while the monitor remained black, I could heard the HDD powering up, the WiFi dongle showing activity and then heard a Windows error sound.

I tried TeamViewer from my phone as I was curious if the PC was actually working and **I managed to connect normally**, viewing my desktop completely okay ( except that the cursor was replaced with a box of glitched pixels ) and then saw briefly a taskbar notification about a "device not properly installed". The monitor wouldn't show anything no matter what.

Could this be a software issue?

Comment: Try a liveCD (or on a pen drive). If you do not run into any issues then a software problem is likely. If you run into the same sorts of problems than a hardware problem is likely.

Comment: What was the "Windows error sound". A number of beeps? If so, how many and who is your BIOS manufacturer (https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+beeps+BIOS+manufacturer).

Comment: Does it also happen when screensaver is enabled??

Comment: The error sound happened while Windows were working. It was a sudden sound and I recognized it as related with "new device couldn't install" ( as when you connect a usb device and can't find drivers ).

Comment: I don't use sreensaver, I have the monitor turned off after 15 minutes of inactivity. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: The screensaver doesn't recreate the problem.